# Delete sheet contents but not macro button Excel Vba

Tags: vba, excel

How can I delete the contents of a sheet including formatting without deleting a macro button?

I am currently deleting the sheet contents

```
sheets("Sheet").UsedRange.Delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearCellsNotButton()

    With Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
        .ClearFormats
        .ClearContents
        .ClearComments
        .ClearHyperlinks
        .ClearOutline
        .ClearNotes
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
```

Comment: `ClearContents` will only delete the values in `Range`, excluding the formatting.